# Issue Scraping data from website that seems to change

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I'm attempting to scrape the data from the PR College table on https://gbr.milesplit.com/athletes/pro/5424599/stats
The Code looks like

```
prTable = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[5]/div/aside/div[4]/table')))
```

Sometimes the response I get is correct, it's a string containing the Personal Records. Other times it just grabs random info off the webpage, and occasionally it fails to find the element. I'm pretty confused as to why it works sometimes, but not all the time. Is there a better way than xpath, or am I using the wrong tag?

Comment: Can you use `BeautifulSoup`?

Comment: I've never used BS, how would I go about using it during this context?

Comment: I've posted an example with `beautifulsoup`

Comment: If the site is dynamic `bs4` won't get it done. @CMB Since you said it gets random info, I think you should not try to get info with `Xpath`. Try to get what you want using the class name, id, etc. This way is more precise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this example how you can parse the page with `beautifulsoup`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


url = 'https://gbr.milesplit.com/athletes/pro/5424599/stats'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

for event, time in zip(soup.select('td.event'),
                       soup.select('td.time')):
    print(event.text, time.text)
```

Prints:

```
800 Meter Run 1:48.05
1500 Meter Run 3:35.01
800 Meter Run 1:48.87
One Mile Run 3:57.02
8000 Meter Run 24:01.50
10,000 Meter Run 30:43.50
800 Meter Run 1:52.25
One Mile Run 4:05.32
1500 Meter Run 3:43.46
800 Meter Run 1:48.05
1500 Meter Run 3:35.01
800 Meter Run 1:48.87
One Mile Run 3:57.02
8000 Meter Run 24:01.50
10,000 Meter Run 30:43.50
800 Meter Run 1:52.25
One Mile Run 4:05.32
1500 Meter Run 3:43.46
```